# Get CURL Easy response content-type

Tags: curl, rust, tcp

I am using the `curl::easy::Easy` crate in Rust to get data from HTTP.

I would like to know how I can get the content-type of the response as the documentation is not clear for me even when I set `show_headers` true.

Here is the code snippet.

```
    let mut easy = Easy::new();
    easy.url(url).unwrap();
    easy.show_header(true);
    easy.write_function(move |data| {
        fs::write(path_uri.as_str(), data);
        Ok(data.len())
    }).unwrap();
    easy.perform().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Easy` has a method named [`content_type`](https://docs.rs/curl/latest/curl/easy/struct.Easy.html#method.content_type), which seemingly is what you want.

```rust
use curl::easy::Easy;

fn main() {
    let mut easy = Easy::new();
    easy.url("https://www.rust-lang.org/").unwrap();
    easy.write_function(|data: &[u8]| {
        // stdout().write_all(data).unwrap();
        Ok(data.len())
    })
    .unwrap();
    easy.perform().unwrap();

    // get the content-type then print it
    let con_type: &str = easy.content_type().unwrap().unwrap();
    println!("{}", con_type);
}
```

```bash
$ cargo run -q
text/html; charset=utf-8
```